# How to interpret regression output for a discrete target variable

Tags: regression

I have to predict amount of items which will be sold. It's a discrete variable. I've trained a regression model for prediction of this amount. Let's pretend that my model predicts that I'll sell 1.5 items. But that is impossible: I can sell only 1 or 2 items. How to interpret this output for, let's suppose, a customer? Should I round output or say like "you'll sell 1.5 items"?

Comment: You could consider using a distribution for discrete, count data, such as the poisson distribution. It sure would describe better the origin of your data, and predict only discrete values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regression model is outputting the conditional *mean* of the sales, i.e., the average.

For instance, next Tuesday, you may sell 1 unit, the Tuesday after 2 units, the Tuesday after that again 1 unit, so on average, Tuesday sales are 1.5, and your model outputs that.

Average sales of 1.5 are consistent with a wide range of possible probability distributions:

[image: probabilities]

R code:

```
mm <- 1.5
xx <- seq(0,10)

opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    barplot(dpois(xx,mm),names.arg=xx,ylim=c(0,0.4),ylab="Probability",xlab="Sales")
    barplot(dnbinom(xx,mu=mm,size=3),names.arg=xx,ylim=c(0,0.4),ylab="Probability",xlab="Sales")
    barplot(dnbinom(xx,mu=mm,size=2),names.arg=xx,ylim=c(0,0.4),ylab="Probability",xlab="Sales")
    barplot(dnbinom(xx,mu=mm,size=1),names.arg=xx,ylim=c(0,0.4),ylab="Probability",xlab="Sales")
par(opar)
```